# wordpress artist

Tags: wordpress, plugins, profiles

How can I make the following in `wordpress` (have googled and searched here):

Singers pages (10-20 singers), each of them has:

- biography.
- discography.
- posts where he is mentioned (by tag probably).

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is all you need to do it in wordpress backend**

- Custom UI Plugin
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
- Custom fields: (Advanced Custom Fields plugin)
  http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

**Here is all you need if you want to code your functions.php**

- First forget about the custom ui plugin
- Custom post type : (register_post_type)
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
- Custom taxonomy: (register_taxonomy)
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
- Custom fields: (Advanced Custom Fields plugin)
  http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

**Steps**

1 - Register your post type and taxonomy (tags) in your function.php

2 - Create custom fields with acf plugin

3 - Create your taxonomies (tags)

4 - Create example post

6 - Create page template that would fetch signers (WP_Query())
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

7 - Associate template to a page of your site.